# Avoiding crash when parsing '@' key in GTM on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, special-characters, google-toolbox-for-mac

I'm providing JSON objects that are to be parsed on different platforms. Based on several sources (for example [1](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html), [2](http://apigee.com/docs/enterprise/content/policies/convert-xml-json-format), [3](https://www.p6r.com/articles/2010/04/05/xml-to-json-and-back/)) I decided to use keys starting with `@` for metadata, which has attribute counterparts in XML.

I've now been told by an iPhone developer that the current structure needs to be changed, since the `@` sign causes GTM to crash. He claims that it's simply impossible to parse structures like this: `{"@name": "value"}`

My dilemma is that I'm serving other clients and languages as well, and I want consistency between the XML and JSON representations of the data, beyond the wish to encode in a way that corresponds to the logical model. I would hope to avoid redesigning the structures because of the needs of a single language, especially since placing `@` signs in keys doesn't violate the rules for proper JSON.

I find it strange if tools such as GTM can't handle JSON structures that not only abide by the standards, but also follow common recommendations and guidelines. *Is the criticism from this developer justified, or is there a way to solve his problem on the client side?*